# Find specific elements in strings in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of strings, which are separated with blanks:

```
[
  "[AT0000 EUR 33.09 32.09 00.0]",
  "[AT0001 EUR 32.34 31.00 00.0]",
  "[AT0002 EUR 34.23 34.01 00.0]",
]
```

I want to get the 1st, 2nd and 5th positions of each line. How is this accomplished?

Comment: Please edit to make your "array of strings" a valid Ruby object. See the answers for guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-split) and then use [`values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at) to get the values at a specific index:

```
array = [
  "[AT0000 EUR 33.09 32.09 00.0]",
  "[AT0001 EUR 32.34 31.00 00.0]",
  "[AT0002 EUR 34.23 34.01 00.0]",
]

results = array.map do |element|
  element.split.values_at(0, 1, 4)
end

puts results.inspect
# => [["[AT0000", "EUR", "00.0]"], ["[AT0001", "EUR", "00.0]"], ["[AT0002", "EUR", "00.0]"]]
```

if you don't want the open/end brackets (`[]`) included you can work with just the text within them as such:

```
results = array.map do |element|
  element[/\[(.*)\]/, 1].split.values_at(0, 1, 4)
end

puts results.inspect
# => [["AT0000", "EUR", "00.0"], ["AT0001", "EUR", "00.0"], ["AT0002", "EUR", "00.0"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want `["AT0000", "EUR", "00.0"]`?

It could be with select and with_index:

```
array = %w[AT0000 EUR 33.09 32.09 00.0]
p array.select.with_index { |_, index| [0,1,4].include?(index) }
# ["AT0000", "EUR", "00.0"]
```